# Swift 5 Firestore: Checking if collection exists in database

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nsexception

I'm trying to check if a certain collection exists in my Firestore database, and here is my code for doing so:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
                db.collection(pickedClass).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

                    if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
                        if snapshot!.documents.count > 0 {

                        for document in snapshot!.documents {
                            let documentData = document.data()
                            let info = documentData["info"] as! [String: Any]

                            output.append(object)
                        }
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTutors", sender: output)

                        } else {
                            self.createAlert(title: "No Tutors Found", message: "Sorry, there are no tutors for this class", buttonMsg: "Okay")
                        }
                }

            }
```

The exception I get from running this apparently comes from the second line `db.collection(pickedClass).getDocuments`, and is as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but  has 0'

terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The bizarre thing is that most times this isn't an issue and the user sees the alert when the collection doesn't exist, but sometimes this happens. I never faced this issue until today, and I've been running this database and this snippet of code for over 2 months now.

Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you're passing to collection().  It would be best not to use a variable at all, and instead hard code a string to illustrate what you're doing and what you expect as a result.

Comment: Note that Firestore collections don't really "exist".  It's perfect valid to query a collection of any name at all, even if it's not seen in the console and has no documents.  A query on that collection will simply show no documents.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm passing the result of a pickerView, which in this case is a string. I guess my issue is understanding why this exception only comes up sometimes and not all the time.

Comment: This is most likely the result of `pickedClass` being `nil` or empty at this particular moment when you use it.

Comment: Agreed with bsod here: your `pickedClass` is empty of null. Log it right before using it to validate that, or set a breakpoint on the line that has an error and run in a debugger.

Comment: @bsod yes that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Hi, I'm implementing FireStore in first time as I study I found this
  answer you can use this below mentioned code.

  ```
  Firestore.firestore().collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME_HERE")
              .document("INSIDE_YOUR_COLLECTION_USE_DOCUMENT_ID_HERE_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK")
              .getDocument { (document, error) in
                  debugPrint(document?.exists) 
                  if document?.exists ?? false {
                      // EXIST
                  } else {
                      // NOT-EXIST
                  }
              }
  ```